# How to rotate map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

I have a map (leaflet) with a route and a marker that simulate car driving on this route. 
I want now the map to rotate when the car is rotating..i have the current coordinates of the car and the target coordinates.

Comment: What platform is this being used on? The device will need some type of native support for directional movement detection and a way for you to access it. Javascript does not provide any built in mechanism for this.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet is not able to do this properly, yet. The ability to modify the [bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)) of the map is a [feature requested since long ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16v2eojZ_l8), but as of today it still needs a lot of work (and we the devs are kinda overwhelmed).

Comment: There are no "few steps". Setting the map bearing is [complicated](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/compare/rotate).